# Can I import and export same-name class and namespace simultaneously in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, typescript-typings, typescript-namespace

Consider class (e. g., `ExampleUtil`) in the file `ExampleUtil.ts`. Currently types which `ExampleUtil` uses, stored in the file `ExampleUtil__TYPES.ts`. No problems when import them into `ExampleUtil.ts`; currently, there is no need for namespace.

When I begin to use `ExampleUtil` in other projects, it turned out that types from `ExampleUtil__TYPES.ts` is context-dependent and it's better to en-capsulate them to namespace. However, the name `ExampleUtil` already using by class, so I need to select the other name for namespace or resolve this conflict by other method.

In my library, I organized the type definitions as:

```js
import ExampleUtil from "./ExampleUtil/ExampleUtil";
import { Type1, Type2 } from "./ExampleUtil/ExampleUtil__TYPES"
import OtherUtil from "./OtherUtil/OtherUtil";
import { Type3, Type4 } from "./OtherUtil/OtherUtil__TYPES"
// other classes, types and functions from library


/** Re-export for other project.
 *  Unlike "lodash", where each function is in separate file, herewith 
 *  all files are in same directory, here the developers can organize source files
 *  by directories, but users does not need to know these directories, because 
 *  they can get everything what they need from single "my-lib.js" file like below:
 *  import { ExampleUtil, Type1, Type2 } from "my-lib";
 *  All "my-lib" classes and functions those has not been used, will not be included
 *  by Webpack to production bundle.
 */
export {
  ExampleUtil, Type1, Type2,
  OtherUtil, Type3, Type4,
  // ... other classes, types and functions from library
};
```

If we wrap `Type1` и `Type2` no namespace `ExampleUtil`, the conflict will occur already here, in `my-lib.d.ts`: we are import class and same-name namespace, then we need to re-export both.

So, can I write the code like

```
//                                Namespace
const parameterForExampleUtil: ExampleUtil.Type1 = { /* ... */ };
//             Namespace         Class
const result: ExampleUtil.Type2 = ExampleUtil.getSomething(parameterForExampleUtil);
```

and if no, which name I may select for namespace? Some good practices from other programming languages allows avoid conflicts between class name and respective namespace? I know that using prefix `I` for interfaces, is the practice like this for namespaces?

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard convention, but you can alias things when importing. The fact that you have a matching class and matching is a _bit_ strange though, and makes me wonder if you're doing something weird when developing your library.

Comment: @Event Thank you for the comment. I know. I think it will be something like `import { Type1 as ExampleUtil__Type1   } from "my-lib"` (prefix solution). I'll use it if will not be more elegant solutions.

Comment: I do use prefixes like `I` for interfaces and `T` for type aliases, and would probably use `N` for namespaces. At some point it can be weird like TToolbar, IIcon or even TError that is not a terror actually. However, I feel like I am really on the safe side and always know that such stuff is TypeScript related.